# Como se faz um array de labels em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, switch, goto

É fato que existe em Assembly (Nasm) e é fato que esta é uma rápida forma de seguir para um ponto do programa entre vários. Aqui há um exemplo de código para x64 onde se escolhe um de cinco códigos de impressão setando 0 ou 1 ou 2 ou 3 ou até 4 na linha `mov eax, 2` (no caso, começa setado 2 e printa `Label 2!\n`).

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 2       ;la index
    mov ebx, 1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov rcx, [la+8*eax]
    mov edx, 9       ;message length
    mov eax, 4       ;system call number (sys_write)
    jmp rcx
_l0:
    mov ecx, l0      ;message to write
    int 0x80         ;call kernel
    jmp _end
_l1:
    mov ecx, l1      ;message to write
    int 0x80         ;call kernel
    jmp _end
_l2:
    mov ecx, l2      ;message to write
    int 0x80         ;call kernel
    jmp _end
_l3:
    mov ecx, l3      ;message to write
    int 0x80         ;call kernel
    jmp _end
_l4:
    mov ecx, l4      ;message to write
    int 0x80         ;call kernel
_end:
    mov eax, 1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80         ;call kernel

section .data

nu  db  '%08X',10
l0  db  'Label 0!',10
l1  db  'Label 1!',10
l2  db  'Label 2!',10
l3  db  'Label 3!',10
l4  db  'Label 4!',10
la  dq  _l0 , _l1 , _l2 , _l3 , _l4
```

É possível fazer isso em C/C++? Tipo algo mais ou menos assim.

```
void print( int index ){
    const label_t print[5] = { _print0 , _print1 , _print2 , _print3 , _print4 } ;
    goto print[index%5] ;
_print0:
    printf("Label 0!\n") ;
    return ;
_print1:
    printf("Label 1!\n") ;
    return ;
_print2:
    printf("Label 2!\n") ;
    return ;
_print3:
    printf("Label 3!\n") ;
    return ;
_print4:
    printf("Label 4!\n") ;
    return ;
}
```

Sou obrigado a usar switch-case e torcer para que ocompilador use array de labels ou há uma maneira de garantir esse funcionamento de array de labels sempre que o programador souber que um valor estará restrito a valores de índice, mesmo que o compilador não saiba?

Comment: Posso perguntar porquê gostaria de tal? Se for ganho de performance: o ganho nisto é tão irrelevante mas acredito que o código fique menos legível e você perde manutenibilidade, no geral, perde com isto.

Comment: Em caso de fórmulas matemáticas complicadas, dá de muitas maneiras para otimizar muito e permitir uso frequente da função sem peso na consciência, tipo em jogos digitais onde cada frame tem que executar a tempo.

Comment: Obviamente, há N maneiras de otimizar um código. O exemplo dado nem faz sentido pra ganho de performance. Na grande maioria das vezes, na minha opinião, o seu esforço vai ser muito maior para otimizar e o ganho disso basicamente nada (isso assumindo que você não está na fase de prototipagem, onde geralmente é feito códigos pra "funcionar", depois melhorado).

Comment: Falta experiência para imaginar o que falo. Flw.

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi seu argumento.

Comment: Dá por exemplo para selecionar uma pequena fórmula entre várias sem várias condições ao invés de fazer as condicionais, o switch ou mesmo uma fórmula enorme. Ganha muito desempenho dependendo do que está fazendo.

Comment: Se for uma fórmula aplicada em um loop para calcular uma tabela, a tabela é formada mais rapidamente.

Comment: O compilador sabe quando há necessidade de uso de tabelas para uso de switch..case. Não tem motivo para fazer uma "tabela manual". Olhe o exemplo com um pequeno switch..case: https://godbolt.org/z/_y2nlx. Foi passado a flag -O3, já que você quer performance. (tive que por alguns valores para ele não ignorar os comandos por não serem usados).

Comment: Aqui, o VS não fez isso em testes anteriores, mas fiz outro teste com mais opções e ele fez. Pena é que não pode anular o tratamento de valores inalcançáveis, como o caso de se garantir o valor de 0 a 10 e, ainda assim, o compilador tratar o -2, -1, 11, 12, etc como default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minha resposta anterior estava errada**, e por isso a eliminei, ainda que outras respostas a suportassem. <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938534/10707951)</sup> <sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938538/10707951)</sup> <sup>[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938549/10707951)</sup>

Como [você disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369157/como-se-faz-um-array-de-labels-em-c-c/369375#comment735425_369188), **é dizer do que não sabe**, mas como você afirmou que existia suporte à tal, **busquei e encontrei**.

Existe uma **extensão do GCC** (e apenas deste):

```
void *s[3] = {&&s0, &&s1, &&s2};

if (n >= 0 && n <=2)
    goto *s[n];

s0:
...
s1:
...
s2:
...
```

Veja: [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada para saber se realmente me serve, pois uso VC++. De qualquer forma, só de saber que existe em dialeto de C de uma extensão do GCC, isso já muda muita coisa.

Comment: Parece que não há. De qualquer forma, você respondeu corretamente. Vlw.